# How I add onclick event to anchor tag in Jquery menu

Tags: jquery

In the below code how can I add an onclick event to `aaa` ?

```
var aaa = $('<a/>')
    .html(yourJson.data[i].name + " <span class='patient-list_txt2-blue'>" + yourJson.data[i].dateTime + "</span>")
    .attr('data-transition', 'slide').click(onclick,'javascript:navigation_message_details()')
    .appendTo(li);
```

Comment: .click(onclick,'javascript:navigation_message_details()') i put this but not working

Comment: The correct syntax is as described here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: You might want to add `preventDefault()` on click to prevent the link from actually triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aaa = $('<a/>',{
    click: function(){
      navigation_message_details();
    }
}).html(yourJson.data[i].name + " <span class='patient-list_txt2-blue'>" + yourJson.data[i].dateTime + "</span>")
.attr('data-transition', 'slide')
.appendTo(li);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add using [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method  from jQuery

```
$('<a/>').on('click', function(){});
```

**Edit:**

***As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().***

Comment: please don't suggest `.bind` - it has been deprecated

Comment: `delegate` is also deprecated - *"As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."*

Answer (score 0):

with your posted code:

```
var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .html(yourJson.data[i].name + " <span class='patient-list_txt2-blue'>" + yourJson.data[i].dateTime + "</span>")
            .attr('data-transition', 'slide')
            .on('click', function(){navigation_message_details();})
            .appendTo('li');
        //------------^^^^------------you were missing the quotes here.    
         });
```